# Spring data jpa calling stored procedure with lots of parameters

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, db2

Is it possible to map an object to all the parameters inside a `NamedStoredProcedureQuery`? I need to call a stored procedure that has over 40 parameters that it takes in. The following code becomes really long and hard to read:

```
@NamedStoredProcedureQuery(
    name="SomeSPName",
    procedureName="SomeSPName",
    resultClasses={ MyEntity.class },
    parameters = {
        @StoredProcedureParameter(name="PACKAGE", type=String.class,  mode=ParameterMode.IN),
        @StoredProcedureParameter(name="APPNM",   type=String.class,  mode=ParameterMode.IN),
        // 40 more required parameters here...
)


public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {

    @Query
    @Procedure(name="SomeSPName")
    long getResult(@Param("PACKAGE") String package, @Param("APPNM") String appnm, /* The rest of the params here */);

}
```

So my question is can I replace the arguments inside `getResult` with an object that has all the getters and setters for the parameters and Hibernate will automatically assign the parameters correctly. For example:

```
public interface MyRepository extends JpaRepository<MyEntity, Long> {

    @Query
    @Procedure(name="SomeSPName")
    long getResult(MyObject params);

}
```

Here, `MyObject` will have fields corresponding to each of the `StoredProcedureParameter` defined up top. Hopefully, this makes sense. I just don't want to put all the 40+ parameters in the `getResult` definition. I'm using DB2 if it makes a difference. Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: If there are 40+ parameters, then I suggest that some re-factoring is needed.

Comment: I don't have access to modify the stored procedure. It's also an old stored procedure that a lot of services use within my job so it can't be changed easily without effecting a lot of stuff.

Comment: You can try to add `@Param("params")` and use SpEL expressions `:#{#params.package}` https://spring.io/blog/2014/07/15/spel-support-in-spring-data-jpa-query-definitions I have never used this approach for stored procedures, it should work.

Comment: @alexvaluiskyi I'm a little confused on how to use that. It says to it add to the Query annotation, but I don't have a query. The query is inside the stored procedure.

Comment: It is my fault. If you does not have query text on code side you can create custom repository. Example in my answer

Comment: @syy Please did you find a way to solve this

Answer (score 0):

```
EntityManager entityManager;

public Long getResult(Params params) {
    StoredProcedureQuery storedProcedure = entityManager
        .createStoredProcedureQuery("SomeSPName", Long.class)
        .registerStoredProcedureParameter("PACKAGE", String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
        .registerStoredProcedureParameter("APPNM", String.class, ParameterMode.IN)
        //...
        .setParameter("PACKAGE", params.getPackage())
        .setParameter("APPNM", params.getAppNm())
        //...
        ;

    return storedProcedure.getSingleResult();
}
```